# Ошибка при запуске сервлета, открывающего pdf-file

Tags: java, pdf, servlet

Я написал обычный сервлет TestServ.
Код сервлета:

```
@WebServlet("/myserv")
public class TestServ extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TestServ() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=file.pdf");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:\file.pdf")) {
            int content;
            while ((content = in .read()) != -1) {
                out.write(content);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.close();

    }


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

При запуске сервлета, идет переключение на Adobe Reader и вылетает ошибка: Adobe Reader не может открыть файл myserv[1].pdf, так как или формат файла не поддерживается или файл поврежден. В чем проблема? Объясните пожалуйста..

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в следующем:

1. Нужно указать размер файла - response.setContentLength(...)
2. Неверно указан путь к файлу, нужно писать "D:\\file.pdf"

Также лучше читать и писать не по одному байту. Таким образом, функция doGet должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=file.pdf");

    File downloadFile = new File("D:\\file.pdf");
    response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(downloadFile)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    out.close();
```

Comment: Сначала cнова не заработало, но я изменил размер buffer указав  вместо 4096 величину downloadFile.lenght() Большое спасибо!